# Use Eclipse Runtime Configuration to start jar file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to start a Java program using an Eclipse Runtime Configuration (`ILaunchConfiguration`). However, I want to provide the program to run as a `.jar` file (as part of the plugin), not as an Eclipse project.

It seems in order to start a Java program from an Eclipse Runtime Configuration I need to specify a project (and main class).

How can I use the Configuration framework to start an arbitrary `.jar` file?

Comment: Can you confirm if I understood your questions correctly. What you need is to be able to launch and debug a `jar` file using the Eclipse JDT but you don't have any eclipse project in workspace for that jar file. Correct?

Comment: Correct. My answer below solves the problem by specifying a class path to the JAR file (so that no project is needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article helps:

http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-Java-launch/launching-java.html

I use the following code to run a `.jar` file which is inside my plugin's `lib` directory:

```
IPath path = new Path("lib" + File.separator + "some.jar");
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(IDs.PLUGIN_ID);
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, path, null);
URI uri = FileLocator.resolve(url).toURI();
File file = URIUtil.toFile(uri);
IPath resolvedPath = new Path(file.toString());
IRuntimeClasspathEntry jar = JavaRuntime.newArchiveRuntimeClasspathEntry(resolvedPath);

IPath systemLibsPath = new Path(JavaRuntime.JRE_CONTAINER);
IRuntimeClasspathEntry systemLibsEntry =
JavaRuntime.newRuntimeContainerClasspathEntry(systemLibsPath, IRuntimeClasspathEntry.STANDARD_CLASSES);

List<String> classpath = new LinkedList<>();
classpath.add(aproveJar.getMemento());
classpath.add(systemLibsEntry.getMemento());

configuration.setAttribute(IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_CLASSPATH, classpath);
configuration.setAttribute(IJavaLaunchConfigurationConstants.ATTR_DEFAULT_CLASSPATH, false);
```